# Why support v4 demo use java code to implement the XML layout?

Tags: android

From the fragment layout Demo:
there is a `simple_list_item_checkable_1.xml`

```
<com.example.android.supportv4.view.CheckableFrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
</com.example.android.supportv4.view.CheckableFrameLayout>
```

and there is a class `CheckableFrameLayout.java`

```
public class CheckableFrameLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
        setBackgroundDrawable(checked ? new ColorDrawable(0xff0000a0) : null);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

I really don't know why the demo write in such way and can I switch it to XML code?
I have tried to Google but I still cannot find any answer.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention, simple_list_item_checkable_1.xml is an item from the listview

Comment: How differently would you do it?

Comment: question is not clear, please elaborate your issue!

Comment: I would like to ask when should I write layout item in such way?

Answer (score 0):

CheckableFrameLayout is a custom display element, not a built-in Android UI widget.  Its behavior is defined in the source code, and its UI is defined in the XML.